# How to generate a boolean value when comparing range of values for particular value in dataframe as part of another query?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, logical-operators

How do I return a boolean value when I compare a range of numbers as part of bigger query(below)?

How I am comparing numbers currently:

```
df.loc[(df.number == 9.0) | (df.number == 10.0)]
```

which returns the row that meets the critria. How do I return a boolean value if the criteria is met inside a bigger query like so (bold is not working because I dont know how to generate a boolean value:

```
flag = **df.loc[(df.number == 9.0) | (compiled_dataframe.number == 10.0)]** and \
(df['label'].loc[1]==' I love everything about the store!' or\
                      df['label'].loc[1]==' Friendly customer service'\
                      or df['label'].loc[1] == ' I found what I was looking for')
```

Comment: You should be able to use [`pandas.DataFrame.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) or [`pandas.DataFrame.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) depending on what you need. Do those functions fit your use case?

Comment: Also, can you add some input and expected output?

Comment: I know someone found a solution which works, but could you still share your program and data? That code seems like a bizarre situation to be in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like you should pass the `index` to the .loc as well

```
((df.number == 9.0) | (df.number == 10.0)).loc[1]
```